# Boolean vs !!. What is better for performance in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have some concerns about my code. What approach in JavaScript is preferential when conversion to the boolean value needed? Boolean(2) or !!2?

Comment: the first one has only one type check.

Comment: You can find this out for yourself.  https://jsperf.com/